# Cannot get MPMediaPickerController to work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
  @IBAction func pickSong(sender: AnyObject) {

    struct MPMediaType : RawOptionSetType, NilLiteralConvertible, BitwiseOperationsType, Equatable {
        var Music: MPMediaType
    }
    var myMediaPickController = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: <#MPMediaType#>)
    MPMediaPickerControler()
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working, I am attempting to pull up the MPMediaPickerViewController to choose a song

Comment: well could you help me then? I am completely lost as swift is my first language, no need to be hostile..., I was simply trying to do the best that I could off of the docs.

Comment: Alright thanks so much, is there any way to transition to a final view controller after hitting done with the song choice?

Comment: Alright sorry I'm new to stack overflow, is that not allowed?